# Html, change columns order in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am using `knockout.js` lib to bind data.
Let's I have next example
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KKhZg/364/)

I have table with data. Table have columns order -

`Name` - `LastName` - `Middlename` - `Age`
and i have 4 functions

```
var namePosition = function()

var lastnamePosition = function()

var middlenamePosition = function()

var agePosition = function()
```

i want bind order of columns in table to values that are returned by this functions.
For example
`namePosition` returns `4`
`lastnamePosition` returns `2`
`middlenamePosition` returns `1`
`agePosition` returns `3`
then table shouls have next column order -
`Middlename` - `LastName` - `Age` - `Name`.
Have you any ideas, how can I do it? (using `knockout` or `jquery`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Diodeus said is a good way to go. You can generate order array using those functions:

```
var order = [];
order[namePosition()] = "name";
order[lastnamePosition()] = "last";
order[middlenamePosition()] = "middle";
order[agePosition()] = "age";

// order===["middle", "last", "age", "name"]
```

And then set *order* observableArray property to your object, using aforementioned order at creation as initial value.

Last thing is to bind cells order and text to new values:

```
<table>
   <thead>  
     <tr data-bind="foreach:order">
       <td data-bind="text:$root.headers[$data]"></td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:users">   
    <tr data-bind="foreach:$root.order">
        <td><span data-bind="text:$parent[$data]"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Info about $root and $parent](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).

With current approach you can change columns order dynamically by code like this:

```
model.order(["name", "last", "age", "middle"])
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/Pw2VE/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple JS array as a look-up table:

```
var fields = [];
fields['Name'] = 4; 
fields['LastName'] = 2;
...etc...
```

Then use `fields['Name']` instead of the numeric value in your code. No need for functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've approached from the perspective that the table will have headings and that these headings need to be re-ordered too. If this is not the case, you can probably disregard this answer entirely. :)

I'm not in the slightest familiar with Knockout - I can't be sure that this isn't a code horror.

However, this fiddle will alter the order of the columns to the one you've given in your example. The values are hard-coded, though (should it be a suitable method) It shouldn't(?) be too much trouble to work out an approach to move them to arbitrary positions.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/KKhZg/368/